# Creating a sequence in a data.table depending on a column

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(R=sample(0:1, 10000, rep=TRUE), Seq=0)
```

Which returns something like:

```
       R Seq
    1: 1   0
    2: 1   0
    3: 0   0
    4: 0   0
    5: 1   0
   ---      
 9996: 1   0
 9997: 0   0
 9998: 0   0
 9999: 0   0
10000: 1   0
```

I want to generate a sequence (1, 2, 3,..., n) that resets whenever R changes from the previous row.  Think of it like I'm counting a streak of random numbers.

So the above would then look like:

```
       R Seq
    1: 1   1
    2: 1   2
    3: 0   1
    4: 0   2
    5: 1   1
   ---      
 9996: 1   5
 9997: 0   1
 9998: 0   2
 9999: 0   3
10000: 1   2
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to add `set.seed` here

Comment: Perhaps, although honestly it doesn't matter which set of random numbers gets generated, I just want to count the size of each streak, one by one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(R=sample(0:1, 10000, rep=TRUE), Seq=0L)
DT[, Seq:=seq(.N), by=list(cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(R)))))]
DT
```

We create a counter that increments every time your 0-1 variable changes using `cumsum(abs(diff(R)))`.  The `c(0,` part is to ensure we get the correct length vector.  Then we split by it with `by`.  This produces:

```
       R Seq
    1: 0   1
    2: 0   2
    3: 1   1
    4: 1   2
    5: 0   1
   ---      
 9996: 1   1
 9997: 0   1
 9998: 1   1
 9999: 1   2
10000: 1   3
```

---

**EDIT**: Addressing request for clarification:

lets look at the computation I'm using in `by`, broken down into two new columns:

```
DT[, diff:=c(0, diff(R))]
DT[, cumsum:=cumsum(abs(diff))]
print(DT, topn=10)
```

Produces:

```
       R Seq diff cumsum
    1: 0   1    0      0
    2: 0   2    0      0
    3: 1   1    1      1
    4: 1   2    0      1
    5: 0   1   -1      2
    6: 1   1    1      3
    7: 1   2    0      3
    8: 1   3    0      3
    9: 1   4    0      3
   10: 0   1   -1      4
   ---                  
 9991: 1   2    0   5021
 9992: 1   3    0   5021
 9993: 1   4    0   5021
 9994: 1   5    0   5021
 9995: 0   1   -1   5022
 9996: 1   1    1   5023
 9997: 0   1   -1   5024
 9998: 1   1    1   5025
 9999: 1   2    0   5025
10000: 1   3    0   5025
```

You can see how the cumulative sum of the absolute of the diff increments by one each time R changes.  We can then use that `cumsum` column to break up the `data.table` into chunks, and for each chunk, generate a sequence using `seq(.N)` that counts to the number of items in the chunk (`.N` represents exactly that, how many items in each `by` group).

Comment: Ok, yup, that looks like it works, can you explain what happened here?

Comment: Also, something like `sequence(rle(.)$lengths)` perhaps is faster?

Comment: Amazing, thats pretty clever

Comment: @alexis_laz - Looks like `rle` would actually slow things down considerably, but that's a neat answer regardless.

Comment: @thelatemail : Hm, indeed about `rle`; my initial assumption was on it avoiding calculation by a group

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but just in case someone needs a faster and easier way:

```
DT[, Seq := rowid(rleid(R))]
```

Explanation:

- `rleid` creates an index incrementing every time a new group of consecutive values is encountered. So `rleid(c('a','a','b','b','a','a'))` returns `1 1 2 2 3 3`
- `rowid` creates for each value an index that gets incremented every time this value is repeated (but not necessarily consecutive). So `rowid(c('a','a','b','b','a','a'))` returns `1 2 1 2 3 4`

It only takes a fraction of a second on this example with 10 million rows.