# Indexing sequence chunks using data.table

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, sequence, chunks

Say I have a data set where sequences of length 1 are illegal, length 2 are legal, greater than length 5 are illegal but it is allowed to break longer sequences up into <=5 sequences.

```
set.seed(1)
DT1 <- data.table(smp = 1, R=sample(0:1, 20000, rep=TRUE), Seq = 0L)
DT1[, smp:=1:length(smp)]
DT1[, Seq:=seq(.N), by=list(cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(R)))))]
```

This last line comes directly from:
[Creating a sequence in a data.table depending on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415749/creating-a-sequence-in-a-data-table-depending-on-a-column)

```
DT1[, fix_min:=ifelse((R==TRUE & Seq==1) | (R==FALSE), FALSE, TRUE)]
fixmin_idx2 <- which(DT1[, fix_min==TRUE])
DT1[fixmin_idx2 -1, fix_min:=TRUE]
```

Now my length 2 legals are properly marked. Break up the >5s.

```
DT1[R==1 & Seq==6, fix_min:=FALSE]
DT1[,Seq2:=seq(.N), by=list(cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(fix_min)))))]
DT1[R==1 & Seq2==6, fix_min:=FALSE]
fixSeq2_idx7 <- which(DT1[,fix_min==TRUE] & DT1[,Seq2==7])
fixSeq2_idx7
[1] 10203 13228
DT1[fixSeq2_idx7,]
 smp R Seq fix_min Seq2
1: 10203 1  13    TRUE    7
2: 13228 1  13    TRUE    7
DT1[fixSeq2_idx7 + 1,]
 smp R Seq fix_min Seq2
1: 10204 1  14    TRUE    8
2: 13229 0   1   FALSE    1
```

And now to test if a Seq2==7 is followed by an Seq2==8, which would be a legal 2 length. I one 7 followed by an 8 and one not followed by an 8. And there I'm stuck. Everything I've tried either sets all fix_min to TRUE or alternation TRUE and FALSE.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Minor fix: `ifelse((R==TRUE & Seq==1) | (R==FALSE), FALSE, TRUE)` should be just `!(R==1 & Seq==1)`. Note that `R` is 0/1 not FALSE/TRUE. Elsewhere, I strongly suspect that you do not need so many parentheses. In `by=`, for example, you do not need to wrap a single vector in a `list()`.

Comment: Not sure, but does this give what you expect? `DT1[, if (.N > 1L) .SD[rep(seq_len(min(.N, 5L)), length.out=.N)], by=.(rleid(R), R)]`. It removes rows where `Seq` is just `1`, and if `1:9`, it changes it to `1:5, 1:4`.. This is to be executed after your first block of code.

Comment: @Arun - Yes, except that I don't want to remove rows in the data at this point because the illegals represent another condition of interest in the data.

Comment: In that case, instead of `.SD`, use `:=` and update `Seq` by checking for appropriate conditions. I think the logic is quite straightforward to get to from the previous comment?

Comment: @Arun - I'll work on it as you suggest, but think I'll do some head scratching as well.

Comment: @Arun, I'll accept this as answer if you'll explain (for people of my level) the workings of your above comment, and not losing the other data of interest.

Comment: @arun, for the purposes of education on data.table, we have a working solution below that may or may not be optimal as it relies on 2 indexes while yours suggested one would suffice. For the purposes of those of use trying to wrap our heads around data.table, would you compare the below answer by Jaap to your suggested approach so we might discern a latitude of approaches to problem solving in the data.frame paradigm.

Comment: @Arun Couldn't get your code working for the whole *data.table*, but figured out an alternative solution. Could you check whether there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set the `fix_min` to `FALSE` when `R == 0` or when `R == 1 & (1 =< Seq < 6 | Seq > 6)`. Then the following should give you what you want:

```
# recreating the data from your first code block
set.seed(1)
DT1 <- data.table(R=sample(0:1, 20000, rep=TRUE))[, smp:=.I
                                                  ][, Seq:=seq(.N), by=rleid(R)
                                                    ][, Seq2 := Seq[.N], by=rleid(R)]

# adding the needed 'fix_min' column
DT1[, fix_min := (R==1 & Seq[.N] > 1 & Seq%%6!=0), by=rleid(R)
    ][R==1 & Seq%%6==1 & Seq2%%6==1 & Seq==Seq2, fix_min := FALSE]
```

*Explanation*:

- `data.table(R=sample(0:1, 20000, rep=TRUE))` creates the base of the *data.table*
- `[, smp:=.I]` creates an index and adds it to the *data.table*
- `by=rleid(R)` identifies the sequences; to see what it does try: `data.table(R=sample(0:1, 20000, rep=TRUE))[, seq.id:=rleid(R)]`
- `[, Seq:=seq(.N), by=rleid(R)]` creates an index for each sequence and adds it to the *data.table*; the sequences are identified by `rleid(R)`
- `[, Seq2 := Seq[.N], by=rleid(R)]` creates a variable that contains a value indicating the length of the sequence
- `fix_min := (R==1 & Seq[.N] > 1 & Seq%%6!=0)` creates a logical vector with `TRUE` values where `R==1` & the length of the sequence is larger than one (`Seq[.N] > 1`) excluding the values where the sequence number is a multiple of `6` (`Seq%%6!=0`)
- `R==1 & Seq%%6==1 & Seq2%%6==1 & Seq==Seq2` filters the *data.table* as follows: only rows where `R==1` & the sequence value is `7`, `13`, `19`, etc (`Seq%%6==1`) & the length of the sequence is `7`, `13`, `19`, etc and only selects the last row (`Seq==Seq2`) from the sequences that meet the other conditions. With `fix_min := FALSE` you set them to `FALSE`.

Comment: Well, no. If you look at DT1[19950:20000] i see a case, starting at 19989 that should be fix_min TRUE for 19989:19993, FALSE for 19994 and then TRUE for 1995:19997. Which is why, in my initial approach, I chose to index the Fix_min again as Seq2, rather than relying on Seq, though frankly I can say I was guessing.

Comment: @Chris See the new update. For the cases you mentioned it's now giving the correct result. Could you check if this is what you want?

Comment: @Jaap- Writing it out and visually inspecting I find 21 cases of a trailing singleton 7 after a 6 (2103/4.4834/5,5703/4,5802/3, 8468/9, 9275/6, 9956/7,10493/4,10822/3,11835/6,12618/9,13055/6, 13353/4,13551/2, 14308/9, 14423/4, 16389/90, 17449/50,17834/5, 19803/4) where 6 was properly set to FALSE, and two cases 8869-8680 where a second run of 6 was allowed and 13216-13228 where a second run of 7 was allowed, both after setting 6 to FALSE.

Comment: @Chris See the update. For that second run of 7 it still gives a `TRUE` for `Seq==13` (which is not you want I guess). I'm trying to find a solution for that.

Comment: @Chris I think I found the correct solution. Can you check?

Comment: Everything ran as you suggested on the prior - all cases handled properly but the 13.  I was thinking of something modulo, but I'll run the latest now.

Comment: One run of 16, 6F, 12F, 13F <- which could have been T as 14T, but the modulo certainly seems to make this more generalizable. All other cases were per the defined rule set. But I think it is something in the Seq >7 ~fix_min:= FALSE, that is tagging 13F. I'm trying to talk myself through the difference in Seq[.N]%%6 and Seq%%6 to see if I understand the difference.

Comment: @Chris When you create a `Seq2` which contains a value indicating the length of the sequence, it's easier to solve I think. I think I've now covered all the cases. Can you check?

Comment: works flawlessly. And uses second index that I suspected was useful, though arun above seemed to suggest was unnecessary in the context of data.table, so perhaps we are not exploiting aspects of data.table that would arrive at the same solution upon one index or? How to invite him back into the education?  And as ever, from both of you it would be most useful to explain, in painful detail, what was happening in your elegant code to those of use who are still <==1000 rep. Thank you for taking the time to bend your mind to this and I look forward to the ensuing discussion.

Comment: @Chris Nice to know that it works. I first wanted to crack the problem, thus preventing to be forced to rewrite the explanation multiple times ;-). Added an explanation now.

Comment: [, smp:=.I], the "sample index" was a nicety used to aid visual inspection of performance of the solution, i.e. when looking at a case beginning and ending at smp(number), but not intrinsic to the solution otherwise. But learned another thing, ".I" for index.