# Remove all values/rows before and after two consecutive zeros

Tags: r, matrix, zero

let's say I have a 10x3 matrix m where I want to check for all zeros and two consecutive zeros in the first column. I want to remove all rows containing a zero in the first column and also all other rows after two consecutive zeros in the first column starting from a certain point in the matrix and either removing values *before* or *after* two zeros in a row.

```
      col1 col2 col3
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2
[5,]    2    0    2
[6,]    2    2    2
[7,]    2    0    2
[8,]    2    0    2
[9,]    2    2    2
[10,]   2    2    2

dput= structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("col1", "col2", "col3")))


expected result=     col1 col2 col3
                [1,]    2    2    2
                [2,]    2    2    2
```

Removing rows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, and 8.

Comment: Please provide code with data (in a machine readable format)

Comment: @HubertL done so.

Comment: Please use `dput` to export your data

Comment: And please also provide the expected resulting dataset

Comment: Done, hope it's all done correctly.

Comment: You have not removed rows 9 and 10 in your expected results

Comment: This should do the trick: `df[!(df[,"col2"]==0 | cumsum( df[,"col2"]==0 & c(FALSE, (df[,"col2"]==0)[1:(length(df[,"col2"])-1)]) )==1),]`

Comment: Perfectly worked, thanks a lot. How could I modify the code to do the same work just for rows "before" two consecutive zeros?

Comment: What about `df[df[,"col2"]!=0&!cumsum(df[,"col2"]==0&c(FALSE, (df[,"col2"]==0)[1:(length(df[,"col2"])-1)]))==0,]`?

Comment: mhh, does not remove the rows before the two consecutive zeros

Comment: only keeps rows 9 and 10 on your example

Comment: When I apply this code to my huge dataframe, it somehow does not seem to work

Comment: What about `df[!cumsum(df[,"col2"]==0&c( (df[,"col2"]==0)[2:length(df[,"col2"])],FALSE))==0,]`?

Comment: Does nothing at all, the dataframe stays the same

Comment: you need two indexes, one for the zeros and one for the length of the zeros and then use the second index, a data.table example here, [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416084/indexing-sequence-chunks-using-data-table/33421100#33421100), perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written you code to solve the following rules:

**Rule A:** Remove rows with a zero in any column

**Rule B:** Remove all rows before consecutive zeros in any column

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 # Row Number
2 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 2  # Column 2
* * * * * * * * 2 2  # * = Remove
B B B B C B A A - -  # Rule Why Removed
```

Where `C` is both `A`+`B` happening. If there are following rows are after row 10 with single (non-consecutive) zeros, they will be removed.

Here we removed 1:8.
Here is my approach:

```
dat <- structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
                  0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
                    NULL, c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
dat

ToRemove <- apply(dat, 2, function(colmn) {
  row.zeros <- which(colmn == 0) # rows with zeros
  if(length(row.zeros) > 0) { # if we found any
     # which of them is the last double
    last.doubles <- max(which(diff(row.zeros) == 1))
    leftof.last.doubles <- "if"(length(last.doubles) > 0, # if double exists
                                1:(row.zeros[last.doubles]-1), # all rows before
                                NULL) # else nothing
    # remove rows with single zeros and all rows before double consecutive 
    unique(c(row.zeros, leftof.last.doubles)) }
})

ToRemove
#$col1
#NULL
#
#$col2
#[1] 5 7 8 1 2 3 4 6
#
#$col3
#NULL

dat[-unlist(ToRemove),]
#     col1 col2 col3
#[1,]    2    2    2
#[2,]    2    2    2
```

Comment: Worked almost perfectly, it's just that it removed one row too much (the first row AFTER the 2 consecutive zeros), which has to be included in the output

Comment: "... either removing values before or after two zeros in a row." I'm a little confused. You don't want both? The way I wrote this was remove any row with a zero. Also, remove any row before and after consecutive rows of zeros. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Also when you say "in a row" you really mean in two consecutive rows? XD

Comment: Oh I think I see. You say remove the following two rows after two consecutive zeros?

Comment: Well, I know it's quite confusing but what I actually want to achieve is, in one case, remove all rows with a zero in the 2nd column and all rows "after" two consecutive zeros in the 2nd column. Another case is the exact opposite, removing all rows with a zero in the 2nd column and all rows "before!" the two consecutive zeros, if I the value is not equal to zero.

Comment: Pretend everything is one case, and tell me where I am going wrong: Look at column 2, remove a row if it is zero, the row after two consecutive zeros, and the row before two consecutive zeros. By this logic, imagine a vector of c(1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 0, 11, 12, 0). You should would be left with c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 12). But your example above removes rows in a way that looks like c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8)... you are removing two consecutive rows, after two consecutive zeros in your example.

Comment: In my example I am removing two consecutive rows, after two consecutive zero, that's correct. Seems like I failed to provide a good example of what I really want, sorry for that. The case of removing rows after two cons. zeros is working perfectly fine, it's just the other case of removing them BEFORE the cons. zeros. Having c(1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 0, 11, 12, 0) I'd wish to have c(11,12).

Comment: I am confused again, so please see my edits that are more relevant to your provided example where I make as clear as possible my confusion

Comment: 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 0 2 2  # Column 2
    2 2 2 2 *  2 *  * *  *  # * = Remove
    *  *  * *  * *  * *  2 2  # What I want. Removing ALL rows/values "left" of 
    the two consecutive zeros. That's what I want

Comment: Please see the edits above. I think I capture all of your rules. I also extend the case to all columns. If you desire ONLY column 2 to remove zeros, simply replace the `apply(dat, 2, function(column) {` with `colmn <- dat[,2] ;` and delete the `)` at the very end after the last `}`.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine, thank you very very much! :)

Comment: Sure. Since this was satisfactory, please mark this post as answered to help others with similar questions.